# How do I view Azure Function host start up time in Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-monitoring

I'd like to know how long the Azure host is taking to start up when instances are added to serve requests. When running locally the runtime summarizes the start up time next to the "host start" log. I'm not able to see this anywhere in Azure AFAIK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best to query the underlying [integrated Application Insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/analyze-telemetry-data) resource:

```
traces
| where customDimensions.Category == "Host.Startup"
```

> 11/30/2020, 7:34:24.132 AM    Initializing Host. OperationId: '03640da2-e000-4af1-8e87-d83382d94347'.
> 11/30/2020, 7:34:24.147 AM  Host initialization: ConsecutiveErrors=0, StartupCount=1, OperationId=03640da2-e000-4af1-8e87-d83382d94347
> 11/30/2020, 7:34:26.877 AM  Starting Host (HostId=nb001681-725949297, InstanceId=745ced93-4234-4ca3-b998-1e6b0af234a0, Version=3.0.14916.0, ProcessId=9196, AppDomainId=1, InDebugMode=False, InDiagnosticMode=False, FunctionsExtensionVersion=(null))
> 11/30/2020, 7:34:26.915 AM  Loading functions metadata
> 11/30/2020, 7:34:26.946 AM  2 functions loaded
> 11/30/2020, 7:34:27.070 AM  Generating 2 job function(s)
> 11/30/2020, 7:34:27.181 AM  Found the following functions: FunctionApp.Function1.Run FunctionApp.HttpTriggered.Run
> 11/30/2020, 7:34:27.229 AM  Host initialized (331ms)
> 11/30/2020, 7:34:27.250 AM  Host started (355ms)
> 11/30/2020, 7:34:27.256 AM  Job host started